# how to validate youtube URL in objective-C?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am trying validate youtube url  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UdQfR4nsXvI .using below code

```
(BOOL) validateUrl: (NSString *) candidate
{

NSString *urlRegEx = @"(http|https)://((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)+([\\.|/]((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*))+";

NSPredicate *urlTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx];

return [urlTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];

}
```

i want also validate any youtube URL format ....

edited code:

---

```
- (IBAction)uplaod_video_Action:(id)sender
{
    NSURL *candidateURL = [NSURL URLWithString:youtube_Url.text];

    // WARNING > "test" is an URL according to RFCs, being just a path
    // so you still should check scheme and all other NSURL attributes you need

    if (candidateURL && candidateURL.scheme && candidateURL.host)
    {
        // candidate is a well-formed url with:
        //  - a scheme (like http://)
        //  - a host (like stackoverflow.com)
        NSLog(@"hallo");
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Please enter the Email" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [alert show];

    }
```

Comment: Refer http://www.raywenderlich.com/30288/nsregularexpression-tutorial-and-cheat-sheet?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+RayWenderlich+%28Ray+Wenderlich+%7C+iPhone+Developer+and+Gamer%29

Answer (score 4):

Use [regexpal.com](http://www.regexpal.com) to check your validation mechanism

[image]

There's a very [comprehensive regex tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/30288/nsregularexpression-tutorial-and-cheat-sheet) on Raywenderlich.com

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
NSString *urlRegEx = @"(^http:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube.com\/watch\?(?=[^?]*v=\w+)(?:[^\s?]+)?$);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use this one

```
-(BOOL) validateUrl: (NSString *) candidate
{

NSString *urlRegEx = @"(?<=v(=|/))([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)|(?<=youtu.be/)([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)";

NSPredicate *urlTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx];

return [urlTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];

}
```

Comment: when i am giving "http:www" in url that one also it was taking

Comment: @user2389500 i think you confused so please use regular expression